# ASP.NET MVC - Dynamically set properties of UserControl not rendering correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, n2cms

As a follow on from one of my previous posts ([ASP.NET MVC2 Master Page - Server side script not rendering, first bracket being escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689494/asp-net-mvc2-master-page-server-side-script-not-rendering-first-bracket-being)) I now having a similar problem.

This time it is with trying to dynamically set the properties of a UserControl.

**For anyone familiar with N2CMS, it is the AdvancedPager control.*

Here is what I am doing:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Products>" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="AddOn" TagName="Pager" Src="~/Views/SharedParts/PagerControl.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
   // content for head section
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <AddOn:Pager runat="server" ID="AdvPager" PerPage="<%= Model.ItemsPerPage %>" Total="<% Model.Count %>" />
</asp:Content>
```

The issue appears to be the value being set in the PerPage or Total property. I can't debug this because I don't have the source, however, I believe it is the same problem I was getting in my previous post because if I replace the dynamic ASP code with hard-coded values it works fine.

Any idea's of a work-around? I have tried putting the entire thing into a `String.Format` but that simply outputs `<AddOn:Pager runat="server"...` to the page, it doesn't actually render the control correctly.

Comment: Blind guess => `<%# Model.ItemsPerPage %>`

Comment: @Arnis: Tried this, same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UserControls with `runat="server"` are a no-no in ASP.NET MVC. They are dependent on the classic WebForms life-cycle which no longer exists in MVC, not even talking about ViewState and PostBack models.

Looking at the name of this control it looks like a pager. There's a [nice collection of HTML helpers](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&ProjectName=mvccontrib) for rendering paginated grids in ASP.NET MVC you might take a look at.

Comment: I have tried removing the `runat="server"` tag but then the control doesn't render at all. I am using this in conjunction with the N2CMS MVC version so for whatever reason I do need the runat attribute.

Comment: @James, yes you need the runat="server" attribute but this doesn't work with ASP.NET MVC. Use a classic web forms application if you want to use server controls, not MVC.

Comment: I have already implemented most of the site using the MVC framework so switching to WebForms is out of the question. So it looks like I will need to roll my own control for this?

Comment: Yes, you will need to either roll your own HTML helper (not control, the notion of control doesn't exist in MVC) or use one of the existing.