# Is this a bug? Or is it a setting in ASP.NET 4 (or MVC 2)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I just recently started trying out T4MVC and I like the idea of eliminating magic strings.

However, when trying to use it on my master page for my stylesheets, I get this:

```
<link href="<%: Links.Content.site_css %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

rending like this:

```
<link href="&lt;%: Links.Content.site_css %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Whereas these render correctly:

```
<link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<%: Links.Content.site_css + "" %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It appears that, as long as I have double quotes inside of the code segment, it works.  But when I put anything else in there, it escapes the leading "less than".

Is this something I can turn off?  Is this a bug?

---

#### Edit:

This does *not* happen for `<script src="..." ... />`, nor does it happen for `<a href="...">`.

---

#### Edit 2:

Minimal case:

```
<link href="<%: string.Empty %>" />
```

vs

```
<link href="<%: "" %>" />
```

---

#### Edit 3:

I have a workaround, I have implemented an HtmlHelper extension so that I can do this:

```
<%: Html.StyleSheet(Links.Content.site_css) %>
```

I like the support for intellisens better, so I'm actually going to stick with that.  Right now, I'm just trying to solve the bug.

Comment: Did you try using single quotes (`'`) around the attribute?

Comment: I hadn't until just now, but it does exhibit the exact same symptoms.

Comment: I think the colon op came with .NET 4.0, so if you're targeting 3.5 or earlier, that may be the cause.

Comment: It reproduced the same thing - target .net 4.0. i think you may be on to something

Comment: Alright, I'm pretty sure that this is a bug.  Who do I report it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me, the compiled output for that is:

```
private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink @__BuildControl__control5() {
    global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink @__ctrl;            
    @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink();
    @__ctrl.Href = "<%: String.Empty %>";
    ((System.Web.UI.IAttributeAccessor)(@__ctrl)).SetAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    ((System.Web.UI.IAttributeAccessor)(@__ctrl)).SetAttribute("type", "text/css");
    return @__ctrl;
}
```

This seems to only happen when the control is inside a `head runat="server"`

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  I'm accepting this, and reporting it to MS.

Comment: Don't think this is a bug, has been in asp.net since 1.1 I believe, the design was carried over into the asp.net view engine.

Comment: @mxmissile:  How do you explain the minimum repro case (Edit #2)?

Comment: @mxmissile: To your point, I am now finding other issues that seem to be related (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987535/asp-net-webform-css-link-getting-mangled )

Comment: @John when you add runat="server" to the head tag, it treats links and script tags as child controls. Try adding code blocks to asp.net controls.

Comment: It happens only with <head runat=server>. Remove the runat and all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the colon. Try `<link href="<%= string.Empty %>" />` instead of `<link href="<%: string.Empty %>" />.`

Comment: I just tested the colon against 4 and still fails.

Comment: Now that you have it working I wouldn't lose any sleep over it. Razor view engine is so much better.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx), `<%:` is a feature of ASP.NET 4.0.  Try targeting 4.0 and see if its still failing.

Comment: I am targeting 4.0.  The colon syntax is only working some of the time.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the runat="server" attribute from the head tag.**

The server generated head tag will render a HtmlLink tag for any link tag. The content of href is taken from source and urlencoded. This is not done for script includes.

**EDIT:**
Write your link tags like following if you cant remove the runat="server" from head tag:

```
<link href="<%= ... %>" runat="" />
```

The following gives an error "runat attribute must have value server"

```
<link href="<%= ... %>myfile.css" runat="" />
```